# CycloneDDS is not working well ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=1 in ros2 humble

Tags: ros2, rostopic, rosnode, dds

First, I configure the .bashrc file with:

```
export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_cyclonedds_cpp
export ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=1
```

But I got following error when run any ros command:

```
ros2: selected interface "lo" is not multicast-capable: disabling multicast
```

and the ros2 nodes can't communicate each other
So I configure lo as multicast and add route with following commands:

```
route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev lo
ifconfig lo multicast
```

After this step, the nodes can communicate each other, but the problem is the ros commands, such as `ros2 node list, ros2 topic list` there is no node and topic listed.

Can someone familiar with this provide solution or suggestions, thanks in advance.